# can't locate css files in paths

Tags: html, path

My directory structure is something like this

```
APPLICATION
|
+-[code]
+-[config]
+-[database]
+-[includes]
+-[src]
+-.htaccess
+-composer.json
```

Pretty self explanatory. The .htaccess guides requests to src/index.php, the code is the middle tier logic, the database is the DAL and the config is configuration INI filies.

The problem I have is that my header file... I have a header.php file in `[includes]` that holds all of my css directives (html5reset, global.css, etc) but for some reason I can't access them. The fact that I can access the header file makes me think I should be able to access the css files (which live in `[includes]`) but they are not loading.

The odd thing is, in firebug, it looks like the actual html page is loading in the place where the css is loading.

this is my call from /includes/header.php

```
<link href="/includes/css/html5reset.css" type="text/css">
```

Confusing question, I apologize. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: If the `css` folder is also in `includes`, wouldn't the path be `/css/html5reset.css`?

Comment: If you enter yourserver/includes/css/html5reset.css into your browser, does it load the file?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird - that is what I am examining... because of my .htaccess, I could be causing an unwanted redirect.

Comment: Or you could be outside your webroot.  What php can access server side (your include) is different than what the browser can request.

Answer (score 1):

in your config.php file you can define a URL (baseurl)

```
define('URL', 'http://localhost/myproject/');
```

then you could use this defined variable like so...

```
<link href="<?php echo URL ?>includes/css/html5reset.css" type="text/css">
```